# Exclude directory from wordpress rewrite issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In /public_html/ I have a wordpress install as well as a directory - 'mydirectory' - that I'd like to protect and be able to access directly.  I've got the protection setup with an .htaccess and .htpasswd file, but I'm only getting 404 errors when I try to access the files in that folder. I've tried just about every re-write option I can find for the root level .htaccess file, but nothing has worked.  I'm curious if I'm missing something outside of the rewrite condition that could be affecting it? I cannot seem to figure out why I can't get this to work! Below are my various .htaccess files and the rewrites i've tried.

**Root Level:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**.htaccess in mydirectory:**

```
ErrorDocument 401 default

AuthType Basic
AuthName "LampreyTrillo"
AuthUserFile file:///public_html/mydirectory/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd in mydirectory:**

```
test:pass
```

**Rewrites I've Tried:**

```
RewriteRule ^mydirectory(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

# disable the rewrite engine in the ignored directory .htaccess
RewriteEngine off 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydirectory/(.*)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(mydirectory) [NC]

#Change last rewrite rule from '. /index.php' to './ /index.php'

RewriteRule ^mydirectory/.*$ - [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mydirectory|mydirectory/.*)$
```

I'm stumped, cant figure out what I'm missing here so any advice or new information would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you still get a 404 when you remove the htaccess file from mydirectory?

Comment: No I do not, but as far as I understand, I need that htaccess to password protect the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(your_excluded_directory|your_excluded_directory_2|your_excluded_directory_3_etc) [NC]
```

just before

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```